# GridView: Can't insert values into another database from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying to insert values from gridview to a database but I get error:
Here is my design : http://pastebin.com/vEm3ciPU

I'm getting

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string." "Line 32:                     dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();"

What can I do?
Thank you,
I'm using a gridview and sqldatasource to bind datatable to gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following

```
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", e.OldValues[0]); 
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Value", e.OldValues[2]); 
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Total", e.OldValues[3]); 
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", e.OldValues[4]);
```

> With Following

```
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", e.OldValues[0]); 
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Value", e.OldValues[1]); 
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Total", e.OldValues[2]); 
DateTime dt; 
if (DateTime.TryParse(e.OldValues[3].ToString(), out dt)) 
    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", dt); 
else
    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", DateTime.Now);
```

---

I am assuming below mentioned schema.

[image]

Comment: Error here : DateTime.TryParse(e.OldValues[4], out dt ! Cannot convert from object to string

Comment: Sorry forgot the type conversion.

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Can you confirm the Table Schema within the post ?

Comment: not really , the table (second) has also Nr. ( auto increment , primary key set ) and doesn't allow nulls

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9864/discussion-between-pankaj-garg-and-inaa-inzii)

Comment: You have enough reputation now. You can join chat.